# How to filter a Group using lambda function in python H2O like pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, h2o

I am looking for doing something similar to [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), but with `H2O` data frame. I haven't find how.

[H2O Group By](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/groupby.html) in python only has specific functions for processing groups, such as `max`, `min`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, you can convert the `H2OFrame` to a list or pandas DataFrame using [`as_data_frame`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.as_data_frame), do the filtering there, then convert it back to an H2OFrame.

Comment: I thought about that, But I would like to avoid it because I am dealing with big data. I think if I do that I will bring the data to the machine running python instead of working with it on the machine running H2O on top of Spark.